# How does a full attack for a Corpse Stirge work?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, attack

I have recently create a corpse stirge, by applying the corpse template to a stirge.
The template gives the stirge a slam attack, that deals 1d3 damage. (1d3-2 after adding strength modifier)

However, when the stirge full attacks, can it use both its slam and its original attack? Or is he forced to choose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**

A creature can always use its natural attacks on a full attack. It attacks with its primary natural attack, then attacks with any and all secondary natural attacks at a significant penalty. The Multiattack feat will reduce this penalty, but it's not necessary to make the bonus attacks to begin with.

Answer (score 3):

The natural attack granted by the corpse creature template does give the corpse stirge an option it didn't have before: instead of using the touch attack and subsequent attach ability (which starts a grapple), it can slam folks; damage will be miniscule (1 point of damage on average).

The DM may designate the new slam attack as the corpse stirge's primary attack. If this is the case, on a full attack the corpse stirge makes a slam attack first as its primary natural attack and then makes the touch attack its secondary natural attack (at a -5 penalty for a secondary natural attack). If the touch attack's successful, the attach special ability activates.

But, more likely, the DM will designate the corpse stirge's slam attack as a secondary attack. If this is the case, on a full attack the corpse stirge makes a touch attack first as its primary natural attack and then--if that touch attack misses and the attach is unsuccessful--the corpse stirge makes the slam attack its secondary natural attack (at a -5 penalty for a secondary natural attack).

The latter is probably a better deal for the corpse stirge since its attach and blood drain are far superior attack methods to its new slam.